# Why selected item in a list moves to a different screen position after the list has been refreshed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created project to show my case. Each time I click on refresh button the selected item moves to a different position on the screen, why is that happening?, however if I move Entities.Clear(); one line lower so after the service has been called, then each time there is a new list the selected item will appear at the exact same spot (which is what I want), Ideally I would like to clear the collection before it goes off to get the data, because instead of the list there is animation that plays, until the service returns (I did not include it here for simplicity). Hopefully this makes sense

```
<Window
x:Class="ReshreshListbox.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
WindowState="Maximized">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox
        x:Name="MyListbox"
        DisplayMemberPath="Name"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Entities}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedEntity}"
        SelectionChanged="MyListbox_OnSelectionChanged" />
        <Button
        Grid.Column="1"
        Click="ButtonBase_OnClick"
        Content="Refresh" />
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind

```
private MainWindowViewModel dataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = dataContext;
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dataContext.Refresh();
    }

    private void MyListbox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyListbox.ScrollIntoView(MyListbox.SelectedItem);
        ((ListBoxItem) MyListbox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(MyListbox.SelectedItem))?.Focus();
    }
```

ViewModel

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<Entity> Entities { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Entity>();
    public Entity SelectedEntity { get; set; }

    public async void Refresh()
    {
        var id = SelectedEntity?.Id;
        Entities.Clear();
        var results = await DataService.FetchDataAsync();
        results.ForEach(p => Entities.Add(p));
        SelectedEntity = Entities.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Id == id);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedEntity));
    }
}
```

Service

```
public static class DataService
{
    public static Task<List<Entity>> FetchDataAsync()
    {
        return Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(500);
            var entities = new List<Entity>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            {
                entities.Add(new Entity() { Id = i, Name = $"I'm number {i}" });
            }
            return entities;
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Because your `OnSelectChanged` is called when you refresh the data. Which will execute `MyListbox.ScrollIntoView(MyListbox.SelectedItem);`

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen But thats fine, because I need it. But why if the selected item was in the middle on the screen, it will now be somewhere else (at the bottom most of the time), but if I clear the collection after service call, and don't change anything else. After refresh it will be at the exact same spot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that when you call `Clear()` *before* awaiting the service method, the `Refresh()` method returns and the dispatcher have time to refresh the `ListBox` just before the service method returns and the remainder of the `Refresh()` method is executed.

When you call `Entities.Clear()` *after* the async call to the service method the `ListBox` is not refreshed before the `MyListbox_OnSelectionChanged` event handler is executed since all code after the `await` happens synchronously on the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  The second part is slightly confusing though, if I set breakpoint in MyListbox_OnSelectionChanged it runs twice, regardles of whether I called Entities.Clear() before or after the async, the first time it has ItemsSource count 0 and SelectedItem null, and the second time its got new collection and new selected item. So it looks  like the ListBox is refreshed in both scenarior by the time it hits MyListbox_OnSelectionChanged.

Comment: The method is called but the UI that you see on the screen is not refreshed. The point is that the UI cannot be refreshed while your code is running on the UI thread. An async method returns to the caller when it hits an await.

Comment: So are you saying that even though the Listbox object says there are no items, the items are still there. Is there anyway around it? I mean I just want the selected item, if it still exist to be at the same position while keeping my async stuff. The problem is that the user can click archive on that item, then the list refreshes, if he/she did not move the mouse at that same position they can click delete. But if its async the item they can click again is a different one, because it moved it, which will be confusing.

Comment: I am saying that you are clearing them items, hits an await which allows the UI to re-render, and then the scroll position is lost and you are getting a slightly different one when the ScrollIntoView method is called. If you do everything at once on the same thread, i.e. without awaiting any async method, this doesn't happen because the rendering engine doesn't get a change to re-render the UI before your code has been executed from start to finish.

Comment: Thank you, it makes sense now. I'll leave the question open for a couple of days, to see whether I'll fetch other answers, and then accept it.